# Can I show contact photos in a public membership list on a WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress

[image][image][image]On a newly built WordPress site for a City livery company, I have created a membership list that members can opt to appear on. This is working perfectly, and the list is showing name, member type, role, email and phone number.

However, if I include the contact image (which works on individual profiles), it just shows as a url.

Is there a solution to this? I know the livery company members will be disappointed if they can't see member photos.

Comment: Are you using civicrm profile search to list the member with their images?

Comment: Hi Pradeep. No - the members just want to see a simple list of all fellow members, showing basic contact details and their profile photo. They are very unsophisticated users! I have attached a screenshot to the post showing the profile fields.

Comment: I have successfully installed the extension. However, it is not fixed yet - see listing2 attachment.   I note that the urls shown for the images include the amend-profile page which is the WordPress page where the member can change their profile and save a picture.

Comment: For example, my image is: https://wccsa.org.uk/members/membership-details/amend-profile/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fimagefile&photo=09_04_Le_Touquet_4_d0dc0c07fe19da0c12781936a5c205b7.jpg.   If I look at my contact page in Civi, the image url is: https://wccsa.org.uk/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Ffile&reset=1&filename=09_04_Le_Touquet_4_d0dc0c07fe19da0c12781936a5c205b7.jpg&mime-type=image/jpeg

Comment: I just pushed a minor typo. Can you try updating your extension code to reflect my new changes?

Comment: Almost there! Images are now appearing but there is one error message see listing3. It reads: Notice: Undefined index: field_name in /home/sites/6a/e/e4289cd3a4/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.profileimageurl-master/profileimageurl.php on line 153

Comment: Just updated code to fix the notice error

Comment: Fixed - thanks a million!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if its a bug or indented to show url in profile search listing. I have just written a small [extension](https://github.com/pradpnayak/org.civicrm.profileimageurl) that converts imageurl into image.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: So kind Pradeep - I will get on to this and let you know how I do. Mike

Comment: Hi Pradeep - it appears the extension has stopped working. Could you possibly look into it? This is an example of an image that once again shows on the listing as a url: https://wccsa.org.uk/members/membership-details/amend-profile/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fimagefile&photo=Karen_Sylva_1b0e8c7134a807f30446b0cd2ce4bf41.JPG